# Highcharts not showing up in ruby web app

Tags: javascript, ruby, amazon-web-services, highcharts, sinatra

Will someone tell me why my high charts aren't coming up on my ruby sinatra web application. I'm trying to pull data from my dynamodb table and put that into charts. I downloaded my dynamodb items into a csv then converted that to a json file hoping that would help. I can go on high charts website and do a demo and it loads in my website just not mine.

This is my synchronize-chart.js

```
$(function() {
$('#synchronized').bind('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
var chart,
  point,
  i;

for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
  chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
  if(chart.renderTo.className != 'chart'){
    continue;
  }
  e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
  point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true); // Get the hovered point

  if (point) {
    point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
    chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, point); // Show the crosshair
  }
}
  });
/**

   * Override the reset function, we do not need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
   */
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
    return undefined;
  };

  /**
   * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
   */
  function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
      Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart) {
        if (chart !== thisChart) {
          if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, {
              trigger: 'syncExtremes'
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
  // https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
  $.getJSON('/covertcsv.json', function(activity) {
    $.each(activity.datasets, function(i, dataset) {

      // Add X values
      dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function(val, j) {
        return [activity.xData[j], val];
      });

      $('<div class="chart">')
        .appendTo('#synchronized')
        .highcharts({
          chart: {
            marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
            spacingTop: 20,
            spacingBottom: 20,
            zoomType: 'x'
          },
          title: {
            text: dataset.name,
            align: 'left',
            margin: 0,
            x: 30
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },
          xAxis: {
            crosshair: true,
            events: {
              setExtremes: syncExtremes
            },
            type: 'datetime'
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: null
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            positioner: function() {
              return {
                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                y: -1 // align to title
              };
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            //pointFormat: '{point.y}',
            pointFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.x:%e. %b \'%y %H:%M:%S}</span> {point.y}',
            headerFormat: '',
            shadow: false,
            style: {
              fontSize: '18px'
            },
            valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
          },
          series: [{
            data: dataset.data,
            name: dataset.name,
            type: dataset.type,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
            }
          }]
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Water-level-chart.js

```
$(function() {

var gaugeOptions = {

chart: {
  type: 'solidgauge'
},

title: null,

    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '140%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      stops: [
        [0.1, '#DF5353'], // red
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.6, '#55BF3B'] // green
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPixelInterval: 400,
      tickWidth: 0,
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: 5,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

     $.getJSON('/convertcsv.json', function(data) {
    // The speed gauge
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        title: {
          text: 'Water Level'
        }
      },

      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Water Level',
        data: [data.waterLevel],
        dataLabels: {
          format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
            '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">water left</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: ''
        }
      }]
    })); // container-speed end
  }); // getJson end

});
```

item.rb

```
class Item
    require 'dynamoid'
  include Dynamoid::Document


  table name: :sensor, key: :key, :read_capacity => 5, :write_capacity => 5

  field :timestamp, :integer
  field :payload, :serialized

  def self.chart_values
    x_data = []
    temperatures = []
    humidities = []
    soil_moistures = []

    # not an efective way to do
    Item.all.each do |item|
      x_data << item.timestamp
      temperatures << (item.payload['temp'].to_f || 0)
      humidities << (item.payload['hum'].to_f || 0)
      soil_moistures << (item.payload['sol'].to_f || 0)
    end
    highcharts_value(x_data, temperatures, humidities, soil_moistures)
  end

  def self.highcharts_value(x_axis, temp, hum, soil)
    {
      xData: x_axis,
      datasets: [
        {
          name: 'Temperature',
          data: temp,
          unit: '°C',
          type: 'area',
          valueDecimals: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Humidity',
          data: hum,
          unit: '%',
          type: 'area',
          valueDecimals: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Soil Moisture',
          data: soil,
          unit: '',
          type: 'area',
          valueDecimals: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  end
end
```

index.haml

```
%head
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/jquery.min.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/highcharts.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/highcharts-more.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/solid-gauge.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/synchronized-charts.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/water-level-chart.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/water-pump.js')}
  %link{rel: :stylesheet, type: :"text/css", href: url('/stylesheets/default.css')}
#container
  #synchronized
  .gauge
    #container-speed
    .pump-control
      %form{method: :post, action: '/take-action', id: 'action-form' }
        %input{type: 'hidden', name: 'action', value: 'start', id: 'action_input'}
        %span{id: 'pumper', onclick: 'takeAction()'}
          start
```

After checking the browser console it says

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:4567/convertcsv.json 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
p.(anonymous function)  @   jquery.min.js:2
getJSON @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   synchronized-charts.js:60
k   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery.min.js:2
D   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors reported in the browser console?

Comment: @Pointy I just checked and Im getting a 404 error

Comment: Well that seems pretty clear: the URL for that JSON file is clearly incorrect (or the file is in the wrong place).

Comment: @Pointy I fixed that and I don't have any errors in console, but my charts still aren't showing

Comment: Is the data properly fetched? Could you post the content of `dataset.data` from `synchronize-chart.js` and `data` from `Water-level-chart.js`?

Comment: @KamilKulig it should be pulling that data from my database I'm using DynamoDB from AWS and I'm using a map type. Idk what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Could you check if that data is actually properly fetched? Do `console.log()` of the variables that I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I did console.log and nothing is coming up.

Comment: @KamilKulig should I make blank json files so they have something to parse into?

Comment: Did you do `console.log(dataset.data)` right before this line?: `$('<div class="chart">')`